# Encrypting URL in Objective-C

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode, encryption

I am using Objective-C to communicate with a PHP script, that works with an API. Although I do not wish for the script to be accessed by anyone else, than the actual iOS App on the users device. As some functions require admin permission, and is essential for the app.

Is there a way I could encrypt the link, so people won't be able to sniff the link? Or somehow limit access of the script.

Regards
Mads

Comment: No a clever user could always intercept URL. But if you `https` and put the bulk of the API inside the body of `POST` request is a good first step. See WWDC 2012 [Protecting the User's Data](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=714) and [The Security Framework](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=704).

Answer (score 0):

Use https (SSL/TLS) and pin the certificate, that is about as secure as you can get. Even the query string is encrypted. Note that the entire URL including the query string is usually saved in the server log file.

This will require a CA signed certificate and they can be purchased for $50/year if you shop around. There are also several CAs that offer free certificates: [Free SSL Certificates from a Free CA](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-free-ssl-certificates-from-a-free-certificate-authority.html)